# Создание дочерних потоков-демонов, независимых от состояния родительского потока

Tags: java, многопоточность

Столкнулся с проблемой. Есть одно потенциальное решение, используя многопоточность, однако, есть пробелы в опыте с многопоточкой. ***(Java + Spring)***

**Проблема:** Необходимо добавить возможность регистрировать консьюмера с помощью REST API, который будет на фоне стучатся в какой-либо сервис и, с периодом времени, собирать информацию из запросов в какую-то коллекцию(костыль, но временный).

**Потенциальное решение:**
На запрос о регистрации нового потребителя поднимать процесс, который будет стучаться с каким-то тайм-аутом в другой сервис, сохранять результаты в коллекцию в контексте приложения, повторить по новой предыдущие шаги; при этом, пока этот процесс работает, главный процесс возвращает клиенту, например, статус процесса (запустился/не запустился) и заканчивает свою деятельность, но дочерний "демон" продолжает свою работу, пока его принудительно не вышвырнут другим запросом.

Хотелось бы получить какой-нибудь совет, чтоб понять, чем и как это можно реализовать

Comment: Если зарегистрировали потребителя, а потом сервер перезагрузился, подписка и факт того что нужно собирать информацию на фоне теряется или должна сохраняться?

Comment: На данном этапе, допустим теряется. Потом можно навернуть сверху механизм, который делает dump консьюмеров и при перезагрузке поднимает их. Сама задача в том, чтоб реализовать механизм поднятие демонов динамически и манипулировать ими